# Finding all possible permutations with 3 Constants

Tags: python, algorithm, math, permutation, combinatorics

since im sure youre all aware of the "Real Donut Shop Problem" (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223345/counting-donuts). So i just start..

I have 3 Integers, all three are entered by a user. with them i need to calculate how many possible permutations they are. I already got some code, it works fine for small integers, if they get bigger, my tool runs for literally days/hours?

**recursive function to calculate possible permutations:**

```
def T(n, k, K):
if k==0: return n==0
return sum(T(n-i, k-1, K) for i in xrange(0, K[k-1]+1))
```

**Explanation:**

- n = Number of Bottles
- k = Number of crates,
- K = Maximum Number of possible Bottles one crate can fit

K is different for each crate, and doesnt need to be full, it can even be empty.

So, as you see, im calculating how many possibilies they are, to fit X given Bottles inside X given Crates, where one crate can fit a maximum of X Bottles.

**Example for better Understanding:**
Lets say, we have:

- 7 Bottles *(n)*
- 2 Crates *(k) -> [k1, k2]*
- k1 fits 3 Bottles *(K1)*, k2 fits 5 Bottles *(K2)* *[k1 -> 3, k2 -> 5]*

So they are **2** possibilities to fit the bottles inside the crates.

Another one:

- 7 Bottles *(n)*
- 3 Crates *(k) -> [k1, k2, k3]*
- k1 fits 2 Bottles, K2 fits 3 Bottles, K3 fits 4 Bottles

**6** possibilities

Above code calculates that flawless, but when i try it with like:

**Problem:**

- 30 Bottles (n)
- 20 Crates (k)
- k1 -> 1 Bottle *(K1)*,  k2 -> 2 Bottles *(K2)*, k3 -> 3 Bottles *(K3)*, k4 -> 4 Bottles *(K4)*.. and so on until k20 -> 20 Bottles *(K20)*, im sure you get the idea..

It takes FOREVER, so im asking you;

**Question:**

how could i improve above code/function?

Comment: You may want to post the question here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might consider a dynamic programming approach: http://codegur.com/32972173/algorithm-to-calculate-possibilities-with-3-constants

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is exponential blowup of the number of calculations made. But these calculations are calculating the same thing over and over again.

The solution is to store the intermediate values AKA memoization.

Here's a version in python 3.2 using functools.lru_cache to do the memoization for you

```
import functools

    def T(n, k, K):
      @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
      def Tsub(n,k):
        if k==0: return n==0
        return sum(Tsub(n-i,k-1) for i in range(0, K[k-1]+1))
      return Tsub(n,k)

    print( T(7,2,[3,5]) )
    print( T(7,3,[2,3,4]) )
    print( T(30,20,list(range(20))) )
```

On my machine the final result is 2172723680407 and is obtained immediately.

If you don't have python 3.2 you can do it like this:

```
def T(n, k, K):
  cache = {}
  def Tsub(n,k):
    key = (n,k)
    if key in cache:
      return cache[key]
    if k==0:
      cache[key] = (n==0)
      return n==0
    v = sum(Tsub(n-i,k-1) for i in xrange(0, K[k-1]+1))
    cache[key] = v
    return v
  return Tsub(n,k)

print( T(7,2,[3,5]) )
print( T(7,3,[2,3,4]) )
print( T(30,20,list(range(20))) )
```

The strange nesting of functions is used to get around the issue that you can't store a list (`K`) as a key to a table.